# element-wise exponentiation cartesian product

Tags: matlab

Consider the vector a=[a_1 , a_2 ,.. a_n] and denote by a^q the vector with each element raised to the q'th power. What is then the easiest way to create e.g. A=[a^1 ; a^2 ; a^3 ]?

Comment: In MATLAB, we denote by `a.^q` the vector with each element raised to the qth power.

Comment: @Jacob: Yes, [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) means if you have vectors with elements `a(i)` and `b(j)`, it will evaluate using every possible pair `[i, j]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `bsxfun` singleton expansion to help with this

```
bsxfun(@power, a, [1:3]')
```

Comment: @Jacob: Yes, thanks... the actual code I tested in MATLAB was `a = [ 1 2 3 4 ]; bsxfun(@power, a, [1;2;3;4])` -- a column vector is needed for the powers.

Comment: perfect! I actually tried that with a row vector before posting the question, but when it failed gave up and asked.

Comment: sure thing! Just didn't think it mattered here.